# How o restrict Generic type implementations in c#

Tags: c#, .net, generic-type-argument

I'm wondering if there is a way to constrain the implementations of a generic type by asking Not to implement a specific interface

Something like

```
public class PrivateGarage<TVehicle> where TVehicle : **not** Itruck
{
...
}
```

This might works but it's less elegant

```
public class PrivateGarage<TVehicle>
{
   public PrivateGarage()
   {
      if(typeof(TVehicle) is Itruck)
      {
         throw new ArgumentException("Truck is not a valid type for private garage");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: No, there's no "negative" constraint. An `ArgumentException` is fine, though you should also reconsider your design, since explicitly wanting to exclude an *interface* is smelly: it suggests the interface is being used not as a contract for available operations but as an implementation distinguisher, which is probably better done by excluding a specific base class or checking a `SupportsPrivateGarageSomethingSomething` property at runtime.

Comment: No, the correct way to do this would be to have an interface specifically for this, like `ICanGoInGarage`, which may itself also implement `IVehicle`

Comment: Your requirement might also break LSP (especially when throwing the exception). See: [What is an example of the Liskov Substitution Principle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56860/880990).

Comment: What benefit is there in generics of requiring a type _not_ implement an interface?

Answer (score 4):

There is an approach you can take to solve this, but it only works well if there is only one discriminant to worry about.

Let's suppose the base interface is `IVehicle`:

```
public interface IVehicle
{
    public void Park();
}
```

In your case, the discriminant is whether or not the vehicle can go in the garage, i.e., is it a "private vehicle"?

The following two interfaces can represent the discriminant:

```
public interface ICommercialVehicle: IVehicle
{
}
                                                                     
public interface IPrivateVehicle: IVehicle
{
}
```

Now you can represent a private garage by requiring `IPrivateVehicle` rather than `IVehicle`:

```
public class PrivateGarage<T> where T: IPrivateVehicle
{
    readonly List<IPrivateVehicle> _vehicles = new();

    public void Park(T vehicle)
    {
        _vehicles.Add(vehicle);
    }
}
```

Suppose you also have a `Truck` type that does not inherit directly or indirectly from `IPrivateVehicle`. In that case if you try to create a `PrivateGarage<Truck>` you'll get a compile error.

This approach does not scale at all well, so it's probably better to take the approach of using properties and checking them at runtime.

---

A slightly different approach is to use interfaces as "Tags". I must stress that this is [considered by many to be a bad design](https://blog.ndepend.com/marker-interface-isnt-pattern-good-idea/).

To do that you'd use an `IPrivateVehicle` tag as a kind of attribute.

Then the hierarchy would be like this:

```
public interface IVehicle
{
    public void Park();
}

public interface IPrivateVehicle {} // Tag interface. Considered bad design.

public class PrivateGarage<T> where T: IPrivateVehicle, IVehicle
{
    readonly List<IVehicle> _vehicles = new();

    public void Park(T vehicle)
    {
        _vehicles.Add(vehicle);
    }
}

public interface ICar: IVehicle, IPrivateVehicle
{
}

public interface ITruck : IVehicle
{
}
```

Then if you had concrete classes implementing `ICar` and `ITruck` called `Car` and `Truck` respectively:

```
var carGarage   = new PrivateGarage<Car>();   // Compiles
var truckGarage = new PrivateGarage<Truck>(); // Does not compile.
```

- An advantage of this approach is that you can use many tags.
- An disadvantage of this approach is that you can use many tags. ;)

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't. The only way to specify constraints is *inclusive*. There is no way to *exclude* specific subtypes. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) for the list of permitted types of constraints.

The reason, most likely, is such a constraint would break polymorphism. If it were possible, it would mean that instances of a *specific* descendant of the actual type parameter, and its all descendants would, could not be passed to the generic class.

A possible alternate way to impose such a constraint is to introduce properties at an `IVehicle` interface such as:

```
public interface IVehicle
{
    bool CanCarryPassengers { get; }
    bool CanCarryCargo { get; }
}
```

However, there's much more to check for a hypothetical `PrivateGarage`, so in the reality, the conditional to allow a particular vehicle in the garage would be much more complicated than a simple negative constraint.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no weay to exclude a type, constraints don't work that way.

A common solution would be to have an interface specifically for this, like `IVehicleThatCanGoInGarage`, which may itself also implement `IVehicle`

```
public interface IVehicleThatCanGoInGarage : IVehicle
{}

public class PrivateGarage<TVehicle> where TVehicle : IVehicleThatCanGoInGarage
{
    ...
}
```